# automatically remount CIFS share

Tags: mount, samba, systemd, fstab, cifs

I've got a windows laptop with a share named 'share'

The share is mounted on an ubuntu server in /etc/fstab

```
//lt145/share /mnt/test/lt145 cifs nocase,rw,cred=/etc/cifspasswd,vers=3.11 0 0
```

It works, but every day when the laptop is turned off and on again the mount does not come back. host is down is the error message.

The only way to get the mount again is

```
umount /mnt/lt145
```

```
mount -a
```

Can this remount be done automatically? What is normal to mount temporary CIFS shares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `noauto,x-systemd.automount` option to the mount in fstab, then the mount will automatically mount when first accessed (not at boot)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab#Automount_with_systemd

Comment: ok will do that and see if it works. thanks!